# How to store and then restore selection mode (vert, edge, face) with and without BMesh?

Tags: python

I want to store selection mode, then switch to other mode, bevel (or other operation), then restore first selection mode.
Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using incorrect terminology. Selection modes stay the same outside of what tools you are using, unless you're using the selection TOOL, which I never use.

Comment: I meant this `select_mode = bm.select_mode` and this  `select_mode = bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[:]
```

will get your current edit selection mode.
It returns which selection mode is active as True. For example:

```
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[:]
```

returns:

```
(False, True, False)
```

meaning Vert mode False, Edge mode True, Face mode False

You can also request the state of a single mode using its number (starting at 0):

```
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[1]
```

returns (in my case):

```
True
```

because I am in Edge Selection Mode.

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ToolSettings.html#bpy.types.ToolSettings.mesh_select_mode